# Apache pig UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm getting a stack trace when trying to run a pig job involving joining the contents of a snappy compressed avro file.

org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.uncompressedLength

The weird thing is that running the code line by line in grunt works fine, and I can even store the contents of the avro file into something else just fine.

[This issue seems to be relevent, but it refers to Spark and not pig](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-spark-user/201410.mbox/%3CD67C31C8-C17D-4DE2-A9A6-43A8BC4B9A18@gmail.com%3E)

Comment: This issue seems to be the result of the way I was using pig embedded python - it doesn't react well to using functions at all...

Comment: I fixed this by moving functions I had placed outside of the class back inside - no idea what was actually wrong so I'll leave this question unanswered if someone has idea of what went actually went wrong. I suspect it is a detail of jython with which I am unfamiliar.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, and solved it by replacing snappy-java-xxx.jar under $PIG_HOME/lib with the latest version downloaded from [Maven](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Csnappy)